Qt Templates in VS 2022
if I create a new Qt Widget Application in Visual Studio Code, the wizzward starts to guide through the process of getting the basic information togehter. With these information some template gets used to generate my sources.
Just as an example, the generated source file looks like this:
MyClass::MyClass(Widget * parent):
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MyClassClass)
{
     ui->setupUi(ui);
}

What I would like it to look like is
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui = new Ui::MyClassClass();
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
MyClass::~MyClass() {
    delete ui;
}

I don't know how these template files are actually called and I don't know where to find and eventually edit them. Can anyone help?
P.S.: I am working on a Windows 11 prof (64bit) PC. All tools like Visual Studio 2022 and Qt are installed in their default paths.
If someone could get me a directory where to spot or a file extension, or something, so that I could find them on my pc, would be great.

Maybe https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html ?

Are these also used if you create a qt project inside visual studio? Well, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the advice.

No, editing these files seems to not change anything to the generated files in Visual Studio. Maybe these templates are only used by the Qt-Creator.

Yes they seem to be specific to Qt creator.
